# Number guessing game using nested loops and if else statements

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I have been assigned to create a number guessing game using a sentinel loop and a nested loop in it.

1. The program has to give user 3 trials.
2. The random number should only change when the user guesses the correct number or the 3
   trials end.
3. The program should exit whenever the user inputs 0
4. After the 3 trials have ended, the game should display a message saying the trials have
   end and display the secret number.

Here is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const MAX_VALUE = 10;
    int const MIN_VALUE = 1;
    int wins = 0;
    int games = 0;
    int userInput;

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "Welcome to the number guessing game." << endl;
    cout << "For each game, you have at most 3 chances to guess a secret number from 1 to 
             10." << endl;

    cout << endl << "Enter a number from 1 to 10. Enter 0 to exit: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    while (userInput != 0)
    {
        int n = ((rand() % MAX_VALUE) + MIN_VALUE);
        cout << n << endl;

        cout << endl << "Enter a number from 1 to 10. Enter 0 to exit: ";
        cin >> userInput;

        for (int trials = 0; trials < 2; trials++)
        {
           
            games++;
          
            if (userInput == 0)
            {
                trials = 2;
            }
            else if (userInput != n)
            {
                if (trials == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Not correct.You have reached your third trials.The correct 
                         number is " << n;
                        
                    cout << endl << "Let's start a new game";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Not correct. Try again: ";
                    cin >> userInput;
                }

                
            }
            else 
            {
                wins++;
                cout << "Correct Guess! Let's start a new game." << endl;
                trials = 2;

            }
            
            
        }

       

            

            
    }



}
```

Following are the issues I have:

1. The sentinel loop starts after the first guess
2. When the 3 trials are done. It doesn't display the message saying the trials have ended
   and the secret number

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. It's the absolute best tool available to follow the execution path through the code and find logic errors. If you don't know how to use it, now is the perfect time to start learning. There's no more powerful tool available to a coder than the debugger, and it's never too early to learn how to use one. Also, you should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Using the debugger, I have been able to fix issue number 2 but I still have one doubt.

cout << endl << "Enter a number from 1 to 10. Enter 0 to exit: ";
        cin >> userInput;

I am not able to figure out if these two lines of code should be both outside and inside the while loop or not.

 It would be a great help if someone answers this.

Comment: Why can't you just test it to see what works and what doesn't? It would take you less time than it did for you to write that comment, and you'd learn something in the process.